# Apache URL Rewrite & All requests run by same PHP file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I don't know if this is possible or really weird but here goes. I need help

1) Doing Apache URL Rewrite for User Folders:
/basepath/group/user/app/

2) All requests must be handled by the same PHP script

```
/somepath/index.php
```

3) And here is the catch, i need PHP script to have access to group, user and app like so

```
http://www.somehost.com/usergroup/username/userapp/
```

should execute say

```
http://www.somehost.com/index.php
```

but be equivalent to

```
http://www.somehost.com/index.php?grp=usergroup&usr=user&app=app
```

I hope that makes sense, Thanks in advance!!!!

OOO After thought!
Basically ALL requests to said domain are handled by same PHP Script and Paths are turned into URI variables? Make more sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?grp=$1&usr=$2&app=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: hmmm cannot get it to work. May I ask what the RewriteCond(s) are doing? I was playing with something like this before asking in here. #RewriteRule ^/apps/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?publisher=$1&app=$2&build=$3 [NC]

Comment: These conditions mean skip real files and directories from rewrite. May i know why do you have `/apps/` in your rule. That is not part of your URLs. Is this .htaccess in root of website or in some sub directory?

Comment: it is right off root. I have a public_html/apps/ and public_html/cdn/ the latter is configured by .htaccess as static content and the apps is just a compiled config file really. so there are 2 sub domains on the domain pointing to apps.domain.com and cdn.domain.com. I have 2 htaccess files 1 ore each, no in root. i tried yours in root and changed accordingly. the Apache server acts like its not even there. my version also.

Comment: it helped me yes, thank you. I've updated question to show what I ended up with. Thanks again.

Comment: But your answer says it is working, so do you still have some unresolved issue?

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
>   ./index.php?group=$1&user=$2&app=$3 [NC]

This works. My Actual live version is:

```
######LOCALHOST (in house dev)
RewriteRule ^apps/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) ./index.php?pub=$2&app=$3&bld=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apps/([^/]+)/([^/]+) ./index.php?pub=$2&app=$3&bld=release [NC]

######PRODUCTION (remote production)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) ./index.php?pub=$1&app=$2&bld=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) ./index.php?pub=$1&app=$2&bld=release [NC]
```